# Not able to retrive control from Listview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview

Basically, I am trying to put validation control in  of Listview. But, I am not able to specify ControlToValidate = "grpNameTextBox".

I tried to put

`((RequiredFieldValidator)ListView1.FindControl("RequiredFieldValidator1")).ControlToValidate = ((TextBox)ListView1.FindControl("grpNameTextBox")).ID;`

in different Events, but not able to do it.

Afterwards, I deleted Validation Control, and put simple Label. Then in 'ItemInserting' event I put this code :

```
protected void ListView1_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t1 = (TextBox)ListView1.FindControl("grpNameTextBox"); // Getting Null Exception here
        if (t1.Text.Trim() == null)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Field cannot be empty");


        }
    }
```

But getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.
Can any one tell me, where I am wrong?

.aspx part is given below :

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                    Text="Insert"  />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Clear" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="grpNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("grpName") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you put the validator inside the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextBox txt_btn = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("grpNameTextBox");

Comment: this is not a proper way to give validation in code behind because whenyou can give validation in aspx page then why to write code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code

```
  protected void ListView1_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
  {
    TextBox t1 = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("grpNameTextBox"); 
    if(t1==null) return; // or exception
    Button btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("InsertButton");
    RequiredFieldValidator rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator)e.Item.FindControl("rfvId");
        if (rfv != null&& btn!=null)
        {
            rfv.ControlToValidate = t1.ClientID;
            rfv.ValidationGroup = rfv.ClientID + "ValidationGroup";
            btn.ValidationGroup = rfv.ClientID + "ValidationGroup";
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not generating textbox id dynamically in listview, so you can directly give controlTovalidate value to "grpNameTextBox" in aspx page.

Assign same ValidationGroup to RequiredFieldValidator as well as Insert button in aspx code, no code require for validation.

Comment: I tried it but as I mention, I cannot give ControlToValidate Property, there, I am getting error.

Comment: But you can give it at design time in aspx page because you are not giving id dynamically. give Text='<%# Eval("grpName") %>'

Comment: If that answered your question, please "accept" the answer! :)